# fmdb(sql) strange error (iOS)

Tags: ios, sql

I got error:

```
 Failed to insert row: Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=1 "table rss has 4 columns but 3 values were supplied" UserInfo=0x10914dc00 {NSLocalizedDescription=table rss has 4 columns but 3 values were supplied}
```

but I have 3 columns in my table:

```
CREATE TABLE "rss" ("name" VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "array" TEXT, "date" DATETIME)
```

"array" TEXT - stores array of 100+ text values

to load and create base I use:

```
    NSString *const kDatabaseFileName = @"rss.sqlite";
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDatabaseFileName];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]) {
    NSString *defaultDatabasePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDatabaseFileName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDatabasePath toPath:databasePath error:nil];
}

FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];
if (![database open]) {
    database = nil;
    NSLog(@"Failed to open database");
}

[FMDatabase setSharedInstance:database];
```

to save my values in base I use:

```
    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase sharedInstance];
        NSMutableArray *parameters = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
        [parameters addObject:shortSelected];
        [parameters addObject:_dataAll];
        [parameters addObject:date];
        //[parameters addObject:date];
        BOOL updateResult = [database executeUpdate:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO rss VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)" withArgumentsInArray:parameters];
        if (!updateResult) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to insert row: %@", [database lastError]);
        }
    NSInteger rowsCount = 0;
    FMResultSet *resultSet = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rss"];
    if ([resultSet next]) {
        rowsCount = [resultSet intForColumnIndex:0];
    }
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Look at the table's schema using the command line. The error clearly indicates there are really 4 columns. In addition to checking that, it is always best to specify the columns in an `insert` statement: `insert into rss(name,array,date) values (?, ?, ?)`. This way there is no ambiguity about what goes where.

Comment: I do not know how work with the command line here, but I add date to database twice and it is works. and use ( ?, ?, ?, ?); insert into rss(name,array,date) not works in my way